# How to keep SharedPrefManager updated in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have created a user login app. After login it's storing all the retrieved data to my `sharedPrefManager` but after that I want it to check for the update and get the changed data every time I  restart my app or update my user details, or just refresh every time I open `profile_Activity(Specific)`.

Here's my `SharedPref`:

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mysharedpref12";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_USER_MAIL = "usermail";
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userid";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE = "userphone";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "usename";
    private static final String KEY_PIN = "pin";
    private static final String KEY_SUR = "surname";
    private static final String KEY_ADD = "address";

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public boolean userLogin(int id, int pin, String phone, String username, String mail, String name, String surname, String address/**, String catagory*/){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID, id);
        editor.putInt(KEY_PIN, pin);
        editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_MAIL, mail);
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_SUR, surname);
        editor.putString(KEY_ADD, address);
        //editor.putString(KEY_CATA, catagory);

        editor.apply();

        return true;

    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null){
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    public boolean logOut(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

    public int getid(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID, 0);
        //return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID, Integer.parseInt(null));
    }

    public int getpin(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_PIN,0);
        /*SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_PIN, Integer.parseInt(null));*/
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
    }

    public String getUserEmail(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_MAIL, null);
    }

    public String getUserPhone(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PHONE, null);
    }

    public String getName() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_NAME, null);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_SUR, null);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_ADD, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a saperate class for sharedPreference:-

**1> AppPreference.java**

```
public class AppPreference {


    public static final String PREF_USERID = "prefUserId";
    public static final String PREF_FNAME = "prefFname";
    public static final String PREF_LNAME = "prefLname";
    public static final String PREF_PHONE = "prefphone";


    public static final void setStringPref(Context context, String prefKey, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(prefKey, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    public static final String getStringPref(Context context, String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        return sp.getString(key, "");
    }

    public static final class PREF_KEY {
        public static final String USERID = "userid";
        public static final String FNAME = "fname";
        public static final String LNAME = "lname";
        public static final String PHONE = "phone";
    }
}
```

**2> LoginActivity.java**

```
 if (jsonObject.toString().contains(Constant.JSON_KEY.RESPONSE)) {
                        JSONObject response = jsonObject.getJSONObject(Constant.JSON_KEY.RESPONSE);

                        String userId = response.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.ID);
                        String fname = response.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.FNAME);
                        String lname = response.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.LNAME);
                        String phone = response.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.PHONE);

                        SignUpDetailsClass signUpDetailsClass = new SignUpDetailsClass();
                        signUpDetailsClass.setId(userId);
                        signUpDetailsClass.setFname(fname);
                        signUpDetailsClass.setLname(lname);
                        signUpDetailsClass.setPhone(phone); 

                        **// store data in sharedPreference**
                        AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_USERID, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.USERID, userId);
                        AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_FNAME, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.FNAME, fname);
                        AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_LNAME, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.LNAME, lname);
                        AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_PHONE, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.PHONE, phone);
    }
```

**3> Profile.java**

```
                        **// get data from sharedPreference**
                        String userId = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_USERID, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.USERID);
                        String strMob = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_PHONE, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.PHONE);
                        String strFirstName = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_FNAME, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.FNAME);
                        String strLastName = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_LNAME, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.LNAME);
```

Here in first class is for a **AppPreference.java** another class is for **Login.java** to **set** all data in Preference and then you can get data anywhere in your application for example see **get** all data in **Profile.java**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So you are saying that every time you restart your app it sign in using keys stored in  AppPreference.java? and updates key values in profile.java?

Comment: Yes you can set all fields data in SharedPreference from API response and get everywhere into your application it's too easy by using this class and simply calling "setStringPref" for set data and "getStringPref" for get data.
if you need every time when app restart then you need to get daat from splash API.
Hope you get what i'm saying to you and it's helps you.